# Getting Hurricane Electric Free IPv6 Tunnel to work on Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ipv6, tunnel

I have used Hurricane Electric Free IPv6 Tunnel before at a different location on a Debian machine and everything worked as expected.

However on a different router and on Windows 10, I can't get a IPv6 connection.

Here is what I have done

Initially I had to go to my router (Netgear R7000) and to stop blocking ICMP. After I stopped blocking I was able to create a tunnel on tunnelbroker.net

I then executed their commands for windows 10 as below

```
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel interface=IP6Tunnel localaddress=192.168.1.101 remoteaddress=209.51.161.14
netsh interface ipv6 add address interface=IP6Tunnel address=2001:470:1f06:31b::2
netsh interface ipv6 add route prefix=::/0 interface=IP6Tunnel nexthop=2001:470:1f06:31b::1
```

All the commands executed successfully, but I still have no IPv6 access. What is the best way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Why not just set up the 6rd connection on the router, rather than try to create the tunnel on the PC?

Comment: @RonMaupin I did not know that was another option. I will look into it to see if I can make it work

Comment: @RonMaupin do I need to use a service for that? It's asking for "6rd (IPv6 Rapid Deployment) Configuration"

Comment: Simply enter the information from HE. The [manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/R7000/R7000_UM.pdf) explains it on page 32.

Comment: It's working now. The only issue is that I travel often, and I need IPv6 for development. I think the best thing for me is to buy a small router which supports 6rd

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm at another house now, do you know if I can place the router with the 6rd configuration behind another router? would that work? or does it have to be the router connected to the modem directly?

Comment: It has to be the device with the public IPv4 address. The HE tunnel needs to be able to directly connect the the IPv4 address.

Comment: @RonMaupin do you know if setting DMZ from the main router to second router with 6rd settings would be enough to get it working?

Comment: That would be a definite maybe. You must make sure that the firewall allows the correct protocol to the DMZ.